# What is the difference between O(|V|) and O(Theta(|V|)) when using depth-first search based on a tree?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

It is easy to see that  the time complexity of depth-first search  is `O(|V|)`

But, recently, I read a book that said:

> If this process is performed on a tree, then all tree vertices are systematically visited in a total of `O(|E|)` time, since `|E| = Theta(|V|)`

I can not understand  `O(Theta(|V|))`.

What is the difference between `O(|V|)` and `O(Theta(|V|))`?

[image]

Comment: An expression like O(theta(|V|)) does not really make sense. Is this written in the book?

Comment: The book said :' If this process is performed on a tree, then all tree vertices are systematically visited in a total of O(|E|) time, since |E|=theta(|V|)' -- 《Data Structures And Algorithm Analysis in C++》(Mark Allen Weiss)

Comment: You must not substitute terms involving the big O (and similar) notations. They really mean set membership instead of equality. Otherwise some funny results would come up: since n = O(n^2) and n^2 = O(n^2) it follows that n = n^2 ...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations

Comment: I want to know the difference between 'O(|E|) , |E|=big theta(|V|) ' and O(|V|)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer:

- `O(|E|)` means it runs in time linear to the amount of edges.
- `|E| = Theta(|V|)` means `|E| in Theta(|V|)` because `O(.)`, `Theta(.)`, ... are sets. Computer scientists are lazy and sometimes write `=` instead of `in`. Knowing that it means the amount of edges scales linear with the amount of nodes.
- `O(|V|)` means it runs in time linear to the amount of nodes.
- `O(Theta(|V|))` is a statement that makes no sense. `O(.)` is something that wants a function, not a set and `Theta(.)` is a set.

---

- `f in O(g)` gives you an upper bound like "*f is better than g (or equally good)*".

  - For example `n in O(n^2)`.
- `f in Omega(g)` gives you a lower bound like "*f is not better than g (or equally good)*".

  - For example `n^2 in Omega(n)`.
- And `f in Theta(g)` means that both holds, "*f is somewhat the same than g*".

  - For example `2n + 4 in Theta(n)` because `2n + 4 in O(n)` and `2n + 4 in Omega(n)`.
- There are also `small o` and `small omega` which exchange the `<=` of `Big-O` and the `>=` of `Big-Omega` by strict comparisons `<` and `>`, so the "*or equally good*" gets dropped.

I put everything in quotation marks because it is all in respect to the meaning of Big-O-Notation, so "*the same*" in terms of **asymptotic growth**.

The exact definitions can be found at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

---

We now approach your specific scenario. In trees the number of edges is always bounded by the number of vertices. Because a node can maximally have one edge to a parent and one to each children. It can not have multiple edges to the same child for example.

By the way the exact number of edges in a tree is always `|E| = |V| - 1`. Because there is exactly one edge for every node (coming from the parent), excluding the root.

So we have `|E| in Theta(|V|)`, because in terms of Big-O-Notation (asymptotic growth) they are "*the same*". So every tree-algorithm that runs in `O(|E|)` can for example be seen as running in `O(|V|)`.

---

Indeed many algorithms run in `Theta(.)` and not only in `O(.)` but most times only `O(.)` is interesting so they just leave the rest. `Omega(.)` or `Theta(.)` are more commonly seen when analyzing problems in general. For example one can prove that **any possible** comparison based sorting algorithm can not be faster than `Omega(n * log(n))` ([search query to find the proof](https://www.google.de/search?q=sorting+lower+bound)).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean theta(V)? if that, then it is easy.
Before that, you need to know the definition of Big-O,it means 
the asymptotic tight upper bound.

if f(n)=O(g(n)), there exist const c and n0, if n>=n0, 0<=f(n)<=c*g(n)

For example if the time complexity is 3n, then it is belong the level of 
O(n). Also, if the complexity is 3, it still belong to O(n).

Theta(n) means the time complexity is bigger than n, but is under O(n), 
at this situation, we call it theta(n)

Comment: Maybe my description is not accurate, I put the picture. I want to know the difference between 'O(|E|)  , |E|=big theta(|V|) ' and O(|V|)